# EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN with OSAtomicAdd64Barrier

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, arm, atomic

I'm getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN) when a block is called (device, iOS 7)

```
[anAFURLConnectionOperation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
    [[ASingleton sharedInstance] incRecv:(int64_t)bytesRead];
}];
```

where

```
@interface ASingleton () {
    int64_t _recv;
}
@end

@implementation
- (void)incRecv:(int64_t)recv
{
    OSAtomicAdd64Barrier(recv, &_recv);
}
@end
```

Any clues? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with iOS (and my brain can't even _parse_ Objective-C), but I'd infer an incorrectly aligned address is geeting passed to the atomic routine (which uses instructions which fault on unaligned addresses) - that usually stems from stack/register corruption, pointer misuse or dodgy casting somewhere upstream.